# Can you help me fix error about Bluetooth Low Energy (C++)?

Tags: c++, bluetooth

I use VS2013 on Win 8.1.

I have a solution with some projects. One of them is a project contain code connect Bluetooth Low Energy. I build it success.

Another project what reference to above project. But when I build, show error "error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS ' ".

I find out why have this error. In "BluetoothApis.h" , condition "#if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_WINXPSP2)" don't happen. Detail :

```
#if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_WINXPSP2)
typedef ULONGLONG BTH_ADDR;
typedef struct _BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS {
 union {
BTH_ADDR ullLong;       //  easier to compare again BLUETOOTH_NULL_ADDRESS
BYTE    rgBytes[ 6 ];   //  easier to format when broken out
};} BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS_STRUCT;
#define BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS_STRUCT
```

Help me!

Answer (score 0):

In your Visual project(s), you have to #define (in compiler's preprocessor options) which version of the SDK you're using (or want to use). So, typically, you would add compiler's preprocessor terms like : 
NTDDI_VERSION=NTDDI_WIN7
_WIN32_WINNT=WIN32_WINNT_WIN7  (if Win7 is your target)

Use appropriate constants for Win8...